# Scriptfu not executing in the correct order, Why?

Tags: lisp, scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm trying to write a basic script for GIMP but it doesn't seem to want to work right.  It should follow this order after I make my selection: Lower active layer, expand selection 2px, floodfill w/ foreground color, raise active layer.  The final product should be a solid color beneath my lines on the top layer.  But with the code i wrote, it jumps active layers, but floodfills on the top layer and not the one below.  Here is the code I have:

```
(define (quick-fill image drawable)
  (gimp-undo-push-group-start image)
  (let* ((layer (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
    (gimp-selection-grow image 2)
    (gimp-image-set-active-layer image (aref (cadr (gimp-image-get-layers image)) 1))
    (gimp-bucket-fill drawable FG-BUCKET-FILL NORMAL-MODE 100 0 FALSE 0 0)
    (gimp-image-set-active-layer image (aref (cadr (gimp-image-get-layers image)) 0)))
  (gimp-undo-push-group-end image)
  (gimp-displays-flush))
```

Comment: This is probably a stupid "is it plugged in" comment, but: Functional languages in general and scheme in particular do not necessarily guarantee an execution order.

Comment: What I want to know is, what is the `let*` doing there, when the `layer` variable it binds is not being used at all.

Comment: @drysdam: not the case of the scheme plugged-in GIMP - it does its stuff in order (otherwise it would be more than useless as an image scripting language)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make a filter that makes a 2-pixel border around an object on the current layer by making a fill behind it on the layer below (at least that's what it appears you're trying to-do), try this:

```
(define (quick-fill image)
  (gimp-undo-push-group-start image)
  (gimp-selection-grow image 2)
  (gimp-image-set-active-layer image (aref (cadr (gimp-image-get-layers image)) 1))
  (let* ((active-drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-drawable image))))
    (gimp-bucket-fill active-drawable FG-BUCKET-FILL NORMAL-MODE 100 0 FALSE 0 0)
    (gimp-image-set-active-layer image (aref (cadr (gimp-image-get-layers image)) 0)))
  (gimp-undo-push-group-end image)
  (gimp-displays-flush))
```

A couple notes:

1) You never use the `layer` variable in your `let*` section, so I've removed it.

2) Gimp doesn't draw or fill or do anything with the active layer ... rather it works on the active drawable.  If you're getting a fill on the top layer when you want it on the layer below, then that means you're passing in the drawable for the top layer, so it's going to fill on the top layer ... switching the active layer to the layer below doesn't change the value of the passed-in drawable.  So in this modification, I've created a new `active-drawable` variable in the `let*` section that gets initialized to the currently active drawable *after* you've changed the active layer from the top-layer to the layer underneath. That way you're filling the drawable that is the layer below, not the original passed-in drawable that is the top-layer. In fact, you don't need to pass-in a drawable argument at all, since you can get the new drawable from the active layer (which is what's done in this modification).